# Enable only TLSv1.2 in apache 2.2.8

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, apache2

As per the apache 2.2 docs https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol `OpenSSL 1.0.1` is required to support `TLSv1.2`, so I've setup `OpenSSL 1.1.1-pre1`

```
$openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1-pre1 (alpha) 13 Feb 2018
built on: Thu Feb 15 01:59:36 2018 UTC  
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1"
```

Below is my Ubuntu Version

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 8.04.1
Release:        8.04
Codename:       hardy
```

Below is my ssl config I've added in `ssl.conf`

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1.2 ##line 92
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:-LOW:-aNULL
```

When am trying to start the apache service am seeing below error

```
$ sudo service apache2 start
* Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                          
Syntax error on line 92 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.conf:
SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.2'
```

This is the first time am ever working on ubuntu apache setup so am not sure other config changes, Do I need to setup anything else after installing `OpenSSL 1.1.1-pre1` for `TLSv1.2`? or is there any other config changes need to be done to make `TLSv1.2` work on apache 2.2.8?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This has been asked and answered so many time you would have to expend effort to avoid an answer.

Comment: @jww I couldn't find any relative that could fix my issue, could you please provide the relevant articles that fixes my issue?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem. I managed to get OpenSSL 1.0.2o installed with the help of the [Build-Scripts package via GitHub](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts), then rebuilt `mod_ssl` from the Apache 2.2.8 source (patching a couple of files along the lines of the attachment on [Apache bug 49034](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49034) to get it to compile).

However, even after having done this, although I'm pretty sure my `mod_ssl` is using the new OpenSSL (rather than the previous 0.9.8 version), I still can't use `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2` in my Apache config. I'm by no means an expert on this, but from a quick skim through the source of `mod_ssl`, I think it might need code changes to recognise other protocols/versions like TLSv1.2 (e.g. the options in `ssl_private.h` only list SSLv2, SSLv3 and TLSv1).

So if you really need TLSv1.2, and you're stuck on that old version of Ubuntu, it may be worth considering seeing if you can build a newer version of Apache from source (i.e. one that is intended to support newer OpenSSL versions).

Answer (score -1):

```
SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
```

That should be all you need.

Comment: thanks for the response, am still seeing the same error with `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2`

Comment: I have the following lines in my httpd.conf:
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:!NULL:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

SSLProtocol TLSv1.2